# eclipse team explorer git jar files are not loaded

Tags: eclipse, git

We have just moved from svn to git, hosted at Microsoft for Visual Studio.
I'm the only developer here using Java in eclipse.  I installed the Team Explorer Everywhere plugin and am able to clone the repository.  But the jar files inside the libraries are shells of their former selves, only the following meta-data:
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:9d3agy7ae0a5be64b38f6e019a8ed6dca4bf60e4882178007qdf1c237dd78b4b
size 722914
I have heard that I need to set (or install) LFS (Large File Service), so I downloaded and installed git-lfs-windows-v2.5.2.exe.  No change in the jar behavior.
If anyone out there knows how to tell Team Explorer Everywhere to turn on LFS, I would appreciate some guidance.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK Folks, I have unblocked myself by cloning the repository again and abandoning my previous clone.  Apparently, either one of the installs I did changed the LFS behavior or the repository wasn't fully configured at the time I did the first clone.  Takeaway: check your jars after cloning and before making code changes.